# Wordpress custom pages CMS

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress

I'm considering Wordpress as my CMS platform for a client site I'm doing at the moment.

However, I need to create a couple of custom 'modules'. One of these modules is a form that people will be able to complete and have a quote, and once submitted, in a special place in the Wordpress panel (like a menu or something), there will be a listing of all the submitted quotes (just fetching it from a table in my database).

Another one is to manage a cafeteria menu, so the client can add a different meal to each day of the week.

I know perfectly how to do this kind of things using some kind of MVC framework and doing it 'by-hand', but I'm just wondering if this would be possible to do with WP and if yes, what kind of tools I'll have to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, yes, WordPress would be a more-than-capable asset to your criteria. But it's whether the learning curve in getting to know WP outweighs using a framework you're clearly already familiar with?

Personally, it sounds you like you're pretty solid with PHP, and considering the fact that, in my opinion, what you're planning on doing is relatively easy, I'd say WordPress is an excellent solution.

I'd recommend reading about [WordPress 3.0's new custom post type API](http://kovshenin.com/archives/custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/), and skimming the basics of [hooks and filters in the Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

Submitted quotes would merely be a custom post type. You'd be better off writing the front-end code (like handling the form, UI etc.) yourself, either within a theme or plugin, then using `wp_insert_post` and let WordPress handle all the database administration. In fact, WP will go one step further and set up the entire admin for viewing, editing and deleting quotes.

[Post meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) (also known as custom fields) is also there for you if you need to store additional information about a quote that doesn't quite fit the post's table structure.

For the menu, this is even easier. I'd say just create a post category called 'Menu', and the client can publish 'dishes' to it as you would with a blog or any similar rolling format.

I've only licked the surface here. Get stuck in with the above, then check out some other goodies like [meta boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and [custom taxonomies](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try a plugin instead of writing something yourself, [Flutter](http://flutter.freshout.us/) might work. It's a little unpolished sometimes but it makes this sort of thing an absolute breeze.